# Swipe ViewController to dismiss - Bug on top

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to implement the swipe to dismiss on a view controller but there is a bug at the top of the screen on the start of swipe.

[image]

**Code :**

```
@IBAction func handleGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.view?.window)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        initialTouchPoint = touchPoint
    } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed {
        if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > 0 {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        }
    } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.cancelled {
        if touchPoint.y - initialTouchPoint.y > (view.bounds.height/2.5) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the bug?

Comment: Look at the initial position of the gray bar at the top.
When I swipe, I can raise it even higher.
And she goes back on her own when I start to swipe.

Comment: @MichelRobico maybe you need to add the safeAreaInsets (let topInset = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top) to the y frame position.